# Vue props with Tailwind class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I need to use a Vue props in a Tailwind class.

The class is `bg-[url('address')]` (background image), where `address` is a prop.

But no matter what I try, I always get the error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve this 'this.icon'.

I tried:

```js
`bg-[url(${this.icon})]`
"`bg-[url(${this.icon})]`"
'bg-[url('+this.icon+')]'
```

I tried to use that syntax with computed too. Like this:

```js
classIcon() {
   return `bg-[url(${this.icon})]`
}
```

My complete code component:

Template:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 p-4 font-lato">
    <div class="bg-no-repeat w-full" :class=`bg-[url(${this.icon})]`>trstestes</div>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <p>
        <span class="font-bold">
          {{ title }}
        </span>
          {{ benefit }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
      default: "Ícone",
    },
  }
}
```

With computed:

Template:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 p-4 font-lato">
    <div class="bg-no-repeat w-full" :class="classIcon">trstestes</div>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
      <p>
        <span class="font-bold">
          {{ title }}
        </span>
          {{ benefit }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```js
classIcon() {
  return `bg-[url(${this.icon})]`
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `style` binding like `:style="{ 'background-image': 'url('+icon+')' }"`. Tailwind extracts classes directly as strings, so it will not see your dynamic classes - see [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use tailwind class like that cause tailwind can’t work with this kind of classing.
What you can do is to create a css variable in html root and change the variable!

```
Class: bg-[url(—icon-path)]
```

And then in scripts do:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(‘—icon-path’, yourUrl)
```